# Google Apps Script autoResizeRow

Tags: google-apps-script

In Google Apps Script I am using [the function `autoResizeRows(startRow, numRows)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#autoresizerowsstartrow-numrows). When I give the number of rows I want it to adjust, it gives the following error: `Those columns are out of bounds.` I adjusted it to below the number of *columns* in the sheet and it resized the *columns*, not the rows. Why is this happening? Is this an error in Google Apps Script?

Comment: "why isn't this code working?" -> provide said code usage

Comment: The following script is taken from the Apps Script Documentation:

`var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

 // Sets the first 15 rows to a height that fits their text.
 sheet.autoResizeRows(1, 15);`

It should resize the first 15 rows heights, but instead will resize the first 15 columns widths.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. The expected behaviour (rows adjust by becoming smaller according to text height) does not happen.

An [issue has been opened in Google's issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78661919). I just starred it, I recommend you do the same if you haven't already.